# Is there a specific way to get the Ip of a computer in Pharo smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside, gnu-smalltalk, pharo-5

I am trying to run an application Pharo that requires data from the Ip of the host computer in which it's running. In general I have to open the code to set it manually in my Pharo code then launch the application. Is there a better and programmatically way of getting the IP address and returning this address automatically regardless of the computer? Say I deploy it to different computer.

Comment: please don't forget to mark your questions answered when you are happy with an answer! For more see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: There is no such thing as "the ip address". Computers can have multiple network connections (wifi, wired) that each have their own address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are searching for `NetResolverName`.

To get name of your computer:

```
NetNameResolver localHostName
```

Then you can use it for the IP address.  If you execute in Workspace:

```
NetNameResolver addressForName: NetNameResolver localHostName
```

You will get a local network address.

In my case:  `#[192 168 1 17]`

**Edit**

You can also directly query it via:

```
NetNameResolver localAddressString
```

Where you will get just:  `'192 168 1 17'`

### Note: If you are getting 127.0.0.1

If you are getting `localhost` address => `127.0.0.1` you probably have issues with the host mapping.
You can test that with via `ping "hostname"` e.g. `ping localhost.localdomain`
which will get you replies from `127.0.0.1`.  If you have correct setup (hosts, DNS, etc.) you should get reply from your IP address.

When I have changed the `hostname` from `localhost.localdomain` to `smalltalk` then ping smalltalk correctly replies with `192.168.10.30`.  Then `Pharo` produces correct result.

Comment: doing so I get the loopback address 127.0.0.1. Instead I need the private Ip like in your case.

Comment: @ludo what does the `NetNameResolver localHostName` return for you?

Comment: It return a ByteString with the name of the computer.

Comment: @ludo could you post the actual name?

Comment: It is how the computer is named: mylinux

Comment: @ludo if you do `ping mylinux` what IP address is queried? (My guess is that you don't have the name to IP mapping done correctly)  The example above was run on windows it correctly returns the IP when pinged.  When I tried on my linux VM with `ping localhost.localdomain` I got `127.0.0.1` return => Pharo has shown `127.0.0.1`.  When I changed the name `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname smalltalk` (the `smalltalk` hostname name is mapped to the `192.168.10.30`) then `ping smalltalk` correctly returns `192.168.10.30` and so does Pharo.

Comment: you are actually right. ping will return 127.0.0.1. Does it mean I have to make change in the /etc/hosts? I changed the name it does not resolve to anything.

Comment: @ludo that depends on your network setup.  The *easiest*, not always correct thou, is to make changes in your `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: It does work fine on windows. I will make some change and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: @ludo you should upvote this answer (in addition to checking it with the green mark). Thanks!